# Between Sola Scriptura Churches, has it happen that there is a difference interpretation to the same verse?

Tags: sola-scriptura

For example, to the 1 Samuel 28 verse, 
Sola Scriptura Church-A teach *"it's Samuel himself who talk"* 
while Sola Scriptura Church-B teach *"it's the demon who talk, not Samuel"*.

Or it will never happen a different teaching something like that because it must be based on the first teaching from the first Sola Scriptura Church ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course - there are thousands of disagreements between Protestants. Why would it be otherwise?

What sola scriptura means is that the scriptures are the highest and final authority. Sola scriptura means that an argument founded on experience, reason, emotion, history, science, or the teachings of past Christians, cannot be used to trump an argument founded on scripture. But it does not mean that the scriptures are perfectly clear, nor that Christians will never have disagreements. Sola scriptura does not promise that we can answer every question, but it does say that when we submit ourselves to listen to God's revealed word in the Bible, that God will speak authoritatively to us through those words as the Spirit guides our understanding.

What you propose, that later interpretations must yield to the teachings of older churches, is the *exact opposite* of sola scriptura.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few explanations for this issue of different interpretations of scripture.

Scripture alone is the sole rule of faith and practice.  So, while there may be different interpretations of a word or two, all Protestant churches agree on the basics (Nicene Creed).  In fact, there is probably more agreement among Protestants than between Catholic and Orthodox and Protestant.

The Bible tells us there are false prophets and false teachers.  Look at the 7 Revelation letters as example.  Paul warns of wolves having already entered.  James warns that men may deceive themselves.  Are all teachers?  No.  Do some presume to be teachers anyway?  Yes.

The idea of first reference as a guide is about the first reference in Scripture, not in a denomination.